# The confuse about Control.InvokeRequired

Tags: multithreading, winforms

It has a situation that the control is instantiating(it's window handle is null) and it's parent control was instantiated.So the system will find it's parent thread id and compared with the control invoked thread id to make sure if it needs to invokeRequire.
But,why the system has to find it's parent thread id rather than find the Form thread id.I mean finding the Form thread id seems like more quickly and simpler?

Comment: InvokeRequired tries to find the ancestor that has a valid handle. It just need a valid handle to call `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and compare it with the current Thread Id to determine whether marshaling is required, also trying to prevent   `MarshaledInvoke` from throwing. All controls should be created on the same STAThread: any parent handle will do, so it gets the first one it can find. The Procedure is ~ the same as [FindForm()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,6264), except the Type check.

Comment: You should probably specify why you're asking this question. If you're trying to create Controls on a non-UI Thread, then don't. If you think that you really really have to (for some reason), make sure that something *pumps*.

Comment: It is not that simple, Form is a .NET class like any other and does not "have a thread".  What matters is which specific thread owns the message queue that delivers messages to the window.  A pure unmanaged implementation detail.  That can only be determined when the native window is created, then the [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) function starts working to supply the native thread id.  In .NET that happens when the Show() method is called.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer, let me deeper understanding about winform.